# Login is not working with newly set password in django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am implementing the `UserCreationForm` and with this I am setting some default `password1` and `password2` for user.After successful creation it sends email to this user instance and after clicking the email user activates and redirect to the `set_user_password` view. The view is posted below. It successfully creates the password for this user  but the user is not being able to login with this newly created password. What might be the reason ?

forms.py

```
class SetPasswordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, validators=[validate_password])
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['password1', 'password2']

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1:
            if not password1 == password2:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Sorry the two passwords didn't match")
```

views.py

```
def set_user_password(request, pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(get_user_model(), pk=pk)
    form = SetPasswordForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SetPasswordForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password2')
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Password created successfully.')
            return redirect('login')
    return render(request, 'user_invitation/set_password.html', {'user': user, 'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
    path('user/<int:pk>/set/password/', views.set_user_password, name='set_user_password'),
```

With the initial password the user can login but after reset the password it doesn't login from both(initial and new) password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you print `form.cleaned_data['password2']`, you should get a empty value, because you are not returning the value from `clean_password2` method. So fix it by:

```
def clean_password2(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
    if password1 and password1 != password2:
           raise forms.ValidationError("Sorry the two passwords didn't match")
    return password2  # <-- here is the fix
```